# serving static content in code structure generated by yeoman for angular fullstack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, yeoman-generator, angular-fullstack

I am following the code structure generated by yeoman for angular fullstack.

I want to include a script called `core.js` in file called `app.html`.

```
<script src="core.js"></script>
```

1. I do not see express.static anywhere in this for serving static files.
2. I tried using it but it did not help.

It can not locate it and gives 404.

How do I get around this ?

It had happened before as well but I could get around it by using express.static and serving files from location pointed by it.

It did not help this time though.

Update:

I have app.html in folder called Music. In same folder, I have a sub folder called js where I have placed my core.js file that is to be included in app.html. I tried to access it using absolute as well as relative path but did not help and still gives 404.

Answer (score 0):

In angular, the scripts go in the relevant subfolder of /scripts. Either in /controllers, /services/, /directives, etc. You then reference them in your html as such:

```
<script src="scripts/controllers/core.js"></script>
```

As for express.static, express is a NodeJS wrapper for HTTP. So that will be the service you create that lives on some Node server remotely. express.static allows the Node server to deliver static content files from the file set at the remote server. It does not go in your angular application.

Comment: then src="js/controllers/core.js" Are you using 'grunt serve' to serve your angular project?

Comment: @I don't have controllers folder yet. Do I still need to put it in path or I need to create a folder with that name?